# cannot change nginx error log file name

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to change the error log file name. Whatever I am doing, I always get the error logs written to the default file name "error.log" when a request gets processed. I have a global and only one error log configuration in main context:

```
user  npcache;
worker_processes  2;

error_log /opt/logs/nginx/error1.log notice;
pid       /opt/logs/nginx/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  error_log  /opt/logs/nginx/error.log notice;
  include ./mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  #Access log configuration
  log_format main '"$remote_addr" "$host" "$http_host" ["$time_local"]'
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"';
  access_log /opt/logs/nginx/access.log main;
. . .
}
```

With this config I am getting error logs written to /opt/logs/nginx/error.log instead of "error1.log".

Am I missing something in the configuration?

I discovered that the issue was related to the second error log in http context that was eclipsing the top-level one.

Thanks

Comment: I am using nginx from: nginx version: openresty/1.9.3.1

Comment: Please post your whole `nginx.conf` and please format it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to post something like this in your nginx.conf, which is probably in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. It goes at the top of the file, outside the events and http blocks. You can also put it in at the server or location level. [Documentation here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

Nginx documentation is excellent, and many queries have been answered on Server Fault and online already. Sometimes a search can save you time having to wait for people to answer your question.

Comment: I discovered that the issue was related to the second error log in http context that was eclipsing the top-level one. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As you've probably discovered you can have error_log at multiple levels. You have have the error log named anything you want, stored anywhere you want.

Answer (score -1):

You apparently can not change the *initial* error log, it's set a compile time. This *initial* log is used to report errors in the config file etc. before accepting connections.

I understand the logic behind this, but I believe that's not a good choice. It means you have to have root access in order to make the /var/log/nginx/* log directory writable for normal users, if you want to run multiple NGINX in your system with different (non-root) users.

@nginx developers: I would suggest to send *initial* errors to STDERR, as the tradition says...

Comment: Or you can simply test a new configuration before trying to restart nginx with it.

Comment: That's not the problem they were having. They answered their own question at some point at the end of their question "I discovered that the issue was related to the second error log in http context that was eclipsing the top-level one."